# How to mock OwinContext.Request.Query

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, owin

I am trying to unit test a method which checks for Query in `OwinContext.Request.Query` and alters it

```
public static async Task SetUpQuery(IOwinContext context, IClientStore clientConfig)
{
    // Get the ClientId from Querystring
    var clientIdQs = context.Request.Query.Where(x => x.Key == Constants.AuthorizeRequest.ClientId).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    // Some more code here
}
```

I am using Moq to mock the context. How do I mock `Query` object which is of type `IReadableStringCollection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a closer look at `IReadableStringCollection`, you will see that it inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string[]>`. What other class/interface do we know that inherits from something similar. `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

So I set out to find a way to mock `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string[]>`. Take a look at the following extension method

```
public static class MockQueryableExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a generic <seealso cref="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;"/>  to a <see cref="Moq.Mock"/> implementation of Queryable list 
    /// </summary>
    public static Mock<T> AsQueryableMock<T, TItem>(this Mock<T> queryableMock, IEnumerable<TItem> list)
        where T : class,IEnumerable<TItem> {

        var queryableList = list.AsQueryable();

        queryableMock.As<IQueryable<TItem>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(queryableList.Provider);
        queryableMock.As<IQueryable<TItem>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(queryableList.Expression);
        queryableMock.As<IQueryable<TItem>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(queryableList.ElementType);
        queryableMock.As<IQueryable<TItem>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableList.GetEnumerator());

        return queryableMock;
    }
}
```

With that done all that was left was to make sure to create some fake data, store it in a dictionary and set it up on the mock of `IReadableStringCollection`

```
[TestClass]
public class OwinContextTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Mock_OwinContext_Request_Query_Should_Be_Queryable() {
        //Arrange
        var collection = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
            {"A", new[]{"1", "2", "3"} },
            {"B", new[]{"4", "5", "6"} }
        };
        //applying extension method
        var queryMock = new Mock<IReadableStringCollection>().AsQueryableMock(collection);

        var requestMock = Mock.Create<IOwinRequest>();

        requestMock.Setup(m => m.Query).Returns(queryMock.Object);

        var contextMock = Mock.Create<IOwinContext>();
        contextMock.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);

        var key = "B";
        var expected = collection[key];

        //Act
        var actual = SetUpQuery(contextMock.Object, key);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }

    public static string[] SetUpQuery(IOwinContext context, string Key) {
        // Get the values from Querystring
        var values = context.Request.Query.Where(x => x.Key == Key).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        return values;
    }

}
```

The above test passes that the linq query called on the context request query works with the fake data provided.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about moq but we use [typemock](http://www.typemock.com) which makes the tests much simpler. I will put it here so other developers can choose

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void Isolate_OwinContext_Request_Query_Should_Be_Queryable()
{
     // Arrange
    var key = Constants.AuthorizeRequest.ClientId;
    var collection = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
      {key, new[]{"1", "2", "3"} },
      {"B", new[]{"4", "5", "6"} }
    };

    // Can it be simpler than this?
    var fakeContext = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IOwinContext>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.Request.Query).
        WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(collection.AsQueryable());

    // Act
    var result = Program.SetUpQuery(fakeContext, null);

    // Assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(collection[key], result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this, just mock whatever value you want to mock,

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetRequestCorrelationIdTest()
    {
        Mock<IOwinContext> owinMock = new Mock<IOwinContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var requestMock = new Mock<IOwinRequest>();
        var headers = new Mock<IHeaderDictionary>();
        string valArr = "TestCorrelationId";

        var keys = new Mock<ICollection<string>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
        keys.Setup(m => m.Add("X-CorrelationId"));

        headers.Setup(m=>m.Keys).Returns(keys.Object);

        headers.Setup(m => m.Count).Returns(1);

        requestMock.Setup(m => m.Headers).Returns(headers.Object);
        requestMock.Setup(m => m.Headers["X-CorrelationId"]).Returns("TestCorrelationId");

        owinMock.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);

        //Assigning the Context to the class
        Utilities.OwinContext = owinMock.Object;

        // Testing the code
        var corelationId = Utilities.GetRequestCorrelationId();

        Assert.AreEqual(corelationId, "valArr");

    }
```